# Why doesn't Nautilus find other locations when gparted is running?

Tags: nautilus, gparted

I had an active `gparted` window open, then opened `nautilus`. As a result, `nautilus` did not list the other partitions on the computer. Once I closed `gparted` and restarted `nautilus`, the other partitions showed up normally.

Obviously `gparted` placed some kind of lock on reading the partitions. I am wondering how this works and what is involved in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GParted uses various utilities to lock partitions to prevent damage that can be caused if partitions are auto-mounted while GParted is running.

For the exact details, see the [gparted invocation script](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gparted/tree/gparted.in) source code.